# Spring : Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, rest

stuck with this error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported WARNING:
```

I tried get method but its working .

My Controller

```
    package com.demoapp.demo.controller;
import com.demoapp.demo.manager.UserManager;
import com.demoapp.demo.model.error.WebServiceError;
import com.demoapp.demo.model.error.WebServiceException;
import com.demoapp.demo.model.user.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserManager userManager;
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
       return user;
        // return userManager.add(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateUser() throws Exception {
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public User fetchUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return userManager.fetch(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/username/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public User fetchUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        return userManager.fetchByUsername(username);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> fetchAllUsers(@RequestParam(value = "include_all", required = false) boolean includeAll) {
        return userManager.fetchAll(includeAll);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public User deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        return userManager.delete(id, user);
    }

    // Exception handler for WebServiceException cases
    @ExceptionHandler(WebServiceException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<WebServiceError> handleWebServiceException(WebServiceException webServiceException) {
        System.out.println("UserController.handleWebServiceException");
        WebServiceError webServiceError = new WebServiceError(webServiceException.getExceptionCode(), webServiceException.getExceptionMessage());

        // This should happen in case of input constraint validations
        if(webServiceException.getExceptionMessageList() != null) {
            webServiceError.setErrorMessageList(webServiceException.getExceptionMessageList());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<WebServiceError>(webServiceError, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // Exception handler for generic Exception cases
  /*  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<WebServiceError> handleException(Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("UserController.handleException");
        WebServiceError webServiceError = new WebServiceError(400, exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<WebServiceError>(webServiceError, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }*/
}
```

WEB.XML file

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>readonly</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.demoapp.demo.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: which method you called, also try to annotate your method with http method, put POST or GET

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")

Comment: Have you tried without the value = ""? Remove it completely; then it just inherits /user from the RequestMapping at the class level

Comment: try to call localhost:8080/SimpleWebServiceApplication/user/add and change vale=''/add'' in addUser method

Answer (score 0):

Add these two in spring-servlet.xml..

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

According your Dispatcher Servlet Mapping(/) change your RequestMapping in top of the controller like this...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
```

Comment: i allready added <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> and <mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: http://localhost:8080/SimpleWebServiceApplication/user and this is my url with post method